# How return back to same fragment class after complete action in android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-fragments

I developing an android app.I used fragmentation In my app ,I want to make a call using implicit intent,for making  call I create a separate activity class and in this activity I write code for make Call.after call end I want to return back to my fragment class,but I unable to return back to my fragment class.After call end it return to my home fragment class instead of calling fragment.Could you tell me what I did wrong in the code.Your help is really appreciated. 
Here is programming flow

Cardeatils -> Caller

After call complete

Caller->Home.

but I want return like this way Caller->Cardetails.

In Cardetails. Code for Calling Activity

```
public class CarDetails extends BaseFragment implements OnClickListener
{
   //
    private void Makecall() 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent i=new Intent(mActivity,Caller.class);
        startActivityForResult(i, 1);
    }


}
```

and implement this method in CarDetails

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(requestCode==1)
        {

            if(resultCode==RESULT_OK)
            {
                //
            }
            if(resultCode==RESULT_CANCEL)
            {

            }
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

Code for make call

```
public class Caller extends Activity
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // call contact app using intent
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + "XXXXXX"));
        setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, intent);
        startActivity(intent);

    }

}
```

Comment: simply finish() it after work done.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
Fragment f = new myFragment();
                FragmentTransaction t = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                t.replace(R.id.frame_container,f);
                t.addToBackStack(null);
                t.commit();
```

Comment: thanks for answer. could you tell me details where to use this code

Comment: use instead of your intent to call your previous class

Comment: i used this code instead of intent but not working it also returning to home instead of CarDetails please help me